# Keep a subject "listening" after some of it's observers are complete/disposed

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I want to connect multiple observables to a common Subject. The observables may be disposed and new observables will be created and be subscribed by the same Subject.

I create and remove several custom UIViews that each contain Observers that emit to the same Subject.

For example:  in myView1, I have:

```
myButton1.rx.tap
   .subscribe(sameViewModel.subject)
   .disposed(by: disposeBag1)
```

and in myView2, I have:

```
myButton2.rx.tap
    .subscribe(sameViewModel.subject)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag2)
```

In this simple example, sameViewModel.subject is the same PublishSubject in a instance (sameViewModel) that does not de-initialize when myView1 and myView2 are removed.

When myView1 is removed, its disposeBag1 is disposed and myButton1.rx.tap emits its onComplete and onDispose notifications. This causes sameViewModel.subject to also complete and dispose. The subject no longer responds to further events from myButton2.rx.tap or other observables that I create later.

**How do I create/configure a observer-subject relationship where the subject stays active while its observers are disposed?**

Can a subject be configured to ignore the complete/dispose events?
Do I need to rewrite the .subscribe to individually handle onNext, onComplete, etc.? Is there some pattern to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `merge` the two tap observables into one observable then subscribe to it. The merged observable will not complete until all of its component observables either complete or error.

```
let taps = Observable.from([button1.rx.tap, button2.rx.tap]).merge()
```

Since you commented that these buttons come and go, you might instead need to use `flatMap`. The function that causes the views to appear would need to emit the tap observables. Again, the parent observable won't complete or error out until all it's children do, but in this case its children are dynamically generated.

```
func displayView() -> Observable<Void> {
    // create and display view
    return view.button.rx.tap.asObservable()
}

let taps = triggerToDisplayView().flatMap { displayView() }
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The flatMap approach worked the way you explained, but when  the flatMap's observable (taps) is itself disposed, the same chain of events happens in my original problem.

Comment: Yes. The taps observable has to reside in the sameViewModel object.

Comment: Perhaps this is getting to a different question. Can this solution be implemented NOT requiring the VM to own displayView() or any knowledge/references to Views? I've been trying to keep my VM silo from the VC and Views.

Comment: Yes. Pass a closure to the VM that knows how to display the view and return the Observable. The VM doesn't know how, but the closure does. In testing, you would pass a different closure that doesn't display a view, but instead returns a testing observable.

Comment: Whew... after some studying, i think I finally understand now flatMap and closures work. Accepting this answer as correct.